# Contract not found during truffle test

Tags: truffle, javascript, truffle-migration, truffle-test

I created and deployed two contracts successfully (with confirmation) using `truffle migrate` like so:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(ReentrancyPot).then(async () => {
        deployer.deploy(ReentrancyAttack, ReentrancyPot.address);
    })
}
```

The second contract has a dependency on the first like so (excerpt from `ReentrancyAttack.sol`)

```
contract ReentrancyAttack {
    ReentrancyPot public pot;

    function ReentrancyAttack (address _pot) public {
        pot = ReentrancyPot(_pot);
    }
}
```

I'm using a test for the first contract and it is successful, however, the second contract is showing as not deployed (`truffle.js` is configured to point to port `8545`)

```
var ReentrancyPot = artifacts.require("./ReentrancyPot.sol");
var ReentrancyAttack = artifacts.require("./ReentrancyAttack.sol");
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || 'ws://localhost:8545');

require('chai')
 .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
 .should();

contract('ReentrancyPot / ReentrancyAttack', function(accounts) {

    it("pot should support deposits and withdrawals", async () => {
        let pot = await ReentrancyPot.deployed();
        let attack = await ReentrancyAttack.deployed();
    })
})
```

I'm getting the following error after running `truffle test`:

```
Error: ReentrancyAttack has not been deployed to detected network 
(network/artifact mismatch)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.then(async () => {
        await deployer.deploy(ReentrancyPot);
        var reentrancyPotInstance = await ReentrancyPot.deployed();
        await deployer.deploy(ReentrancyAttack, reentrancyPotInstance.address)
    });
}
```

Comment: That leaves me with the following problem when running `truffle migrate`:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
    at deployer.deploy.then (/Users/p/Dev/experimental/solidity-nemesis/tests/solidity/migrations/2_contract_migration.js:8:65)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-deployer/src/deferredchain.js:20:1
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:118:7)

Comment: my fault... I didn't remember right that deployer.deploy is not returning the instance. Let me rewrite the answer...

Comment: The answer is updated. Btw.. you can use await for better readability.

Comment: Btw... you can save the trouble with ``chai-as-promised`` and make your tests more readable and compact if you use async/await in your tests too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The following worked:

    deployer.deploy(ReentrancyPot).then(async () => {
        let reentrancyPotInstance = await ReentrancyPot.deployed();
        await deployer.deploy(ReentrancyAttack, reentrancyPotInstance.address)
    });

Comment: I do use async / await in my tests, unfortunately chai was required because of a version problem (if I remember correctly).